# How to cite the articles published in Transportation Research Board?

Tags: bibtex

I want to cite the following article in bibtex.

http://pubsindex.trb.org/view/2008/C/864534

I used "article" in my bib file and my advisor said that "this is not an article". Then what should I use? "incollection" or something else? Attached is the bibtex with "article" (which is wrong according to my advisor). Thank you!

```
@article{Peter:etal:clim:2008,
  title =    {Climate Variability And Change With Implications For
                  Transportation},
  author =   {Peterson, Thomas C. and Mcguirk, Marjorie and Houston,
                  Tamara G. and Horvitz, Andrew H. and Wehner, Michael F.},
  journal =  {Transportation Research Board},
  year =     2008,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Transportation Research Board is not a journal but the publisher/publishing institution, which I imagine is your advisor's objection.  As such I think `techreport` is the most fitting, all you need to do to populate the required fields with your current bib entry is change the `journal` to `institution`.

```
@techreport{Peter:etal:clim:2008,
  title = {Climate Variability And Change With Implications For Transportation},
  author = {Peterson, Thomas C. and Mcguirk, Marjorie and Houston, Tamara G. and Horvitz, Andrew H. and Wehner, Michael F.},
  institution = {Transportation Research Board},
  year = 2008,
}
```

See http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/bibformat.html or http://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/bibtx-7.html for more information on the other entry types and their required/optional keys.

Given the issue you have is that your advisor has told you something is incorrect, I would also encourage asking them what they regard as correct.  They are presumably the person you need to satisfy on this matter.